# Python beginner, why is math returning NaN?

Tags: python, math

I've got this bit of code for class I'm in but I can't figure out why I'm returning NaN.

I've never used the math module before.

Here is the code:

```
import random as rndm
import math
# helper function to start and restart the game
def get_guesses(low, high):
    global guesses
    #x = low - high + 1
    #guesses = math.log(x, 2)
    guesses = math.log(low - high + 1, 2)
    return guesses

def new_game():
    global secret_number, guesses, first
    if first:
        first = False
        secret_number = rndm.randrange(0, 100)
        guesses = get_guesses(0, 99)
    print guesses
    print secret_number
```

Comment: The `guesses`  value really shouldn't be both a global and a return value. Make up your mind. :)

Comment: Good point!!! Thank you! (:

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you are using the global keyword your program structure is wrong.

Comment: You are calculating the logarithm of a negative number. Though I'd think that would throw ValueError rather than returning NaN.

Comment: Ricky, I'm learning. I know I shouldn't be using them but I'm still trying to grasp most of the concepts!! I'm not doing it just to do it! lol

Comment: Inter, should I try using abs()? I'll see if that has any effect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
math.log(low - high + 1, 2)
```

You pass `low = 0` and `high = 99` so the equation is lower than zero: `0 - 99 + 1 = -98`.

The logarithm of negative numbers is in the [complex number plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), which is not supported by the `math` module (it deals with real numbers only).

So what you get is a value error:

```
>>> math.log(0 - 99 + 1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    math.log(0 - 99 + 1, 2)
ValueError: math domain error
```

---

If you wanted to work with complex numbers, you could use the [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) module:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.log(0 - 99 + 1, 2)
(6.614709844115209+4.532360141827194j)
```

But I doubt that is really what you’re going for here ;)

Comment: How am I getting a negative when I don't subtract anything from high and add one?

Comment: @acollection_ I think I explained that part? `low` is 0, and `high` is 99, and you are doing `low - high + 1` which is `0 - 99 + 1 = -98`. You probably meant to subtract `low` from `high` instead: `high - low + 1 = 99 - 0 + 1 = 100`.

Comment: Yessss. I understand now. Sorry, it's been along night, hahaha. I reversed the numbers and once I realized what I had done, I came back and noticed that you actually told me what the problem was, hahaha. Thank you sir!!

Comment: And now I understand the math module more! So thank you for that also (:

Comment: You’re welcome, glad I could help :) Please remember to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) if it solved your problem to mark the question as resolved.